# Creating an object in Swift using the Objective-C factory method gives a compiler error

Tags: objective-c, swift, compiler-errors, orsserialport

I'm trying to initiate a serial connection using `ORSSerialport`, an Objective-C serial library. I have already used it successfully to find all serial ports but am having problems opening a connection.

The documentation shows the opening of a port as such:

```
ORSSerialPort *serialPort = [ORSSerialPort serialPortWithPath:@"/dev/cu.KeySerial1"];
```

I have written the following:

```
let serialPort: ORSSerialPort.serialPortWithPath(serialListPullDown.selectedItem)
```

However, Xcode isn't autocompleting my method and won't compile. Giving me the error "serialPortWithPath is not a member type of ORSSerialport". I have the bridging header set up correctly and I have used another class in the same library already with a similar syntax with no problems. What has happened here?

Comment: Try something like ORSSerialPort(withPath:"path"). This has worked for me in some cases.

Comment: Or, more generally, type `ORSSerialPort(` and see what autocompletion says.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer:** Create the object with

```
let serialPort = ORSSerialPort(path:"/dev/cu.KeySerial1")
```

**Details:** The Objective-C factory method

```
+ (ORSSerialPort *)serialPortWithPath:(NSString *)devicePath;
```

is mapped to Swift as

```
init!(path devicePath: String!) -> ORSSerialPort
```

This is documented in ["Interacting with Objective-C APIs"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/interactingwithobjective-capis.html) (thanks to [Nate Cook](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59541/nate-cook)!):

> For consistency and simplicity, Objective-C factory methods get mapped
>   as convenience initializers in Swift. This mapping allows them to be
>   used with the same concise, clear syntax as initializers.

That means that the factory method is mapped to the *same Swift method* as the
Objective-C init method

```
- (id)initWithPath:(NSString *)devicePath;
```

Both would be called from Swift as

```
let serialPort = ORSSerialPort(path:"/dev/cu.KeySerial1")
```

and it turns out that this calls the *init* method. As a consequence,
the *factory* method cannot be called from Swift.

Comment: No idea where, but I think I read something from the Swift team that said they were privileging initializers over factory methods when there were matching pairs.

Comment: Oh, it's in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/interactingwithobjective-capis.html): "For consistency and simplicity, Objective-C factory methods get mapped as convenience initializers in Swift. This mapping allows them to be used with the same concise, clear syntax as initializers." The more you know *

Comment: @NateCook: You are right and I already had this in mind, but I could not figure how exactly `+ (ORSSerialPort *)serialPortWithPath:(NSString *)devicePath;` is mapped. The compiler seems to use some heuristic and determines that `ORS` is a prefix like "NS" or "UI".

Comment: Yeah, there must be some interesting mapping going on. It's neat how code that properly follows the conventions of Objective-C can be mapped cleanly into Swift.

Comment: @NateCook: I will fix the answer with your information, thanks!

Comment: @NateCook: Your first comment seems to be correct. I made a small test with a class `MRObject` having an init method `-(instancetype)initWithString:(NSString *)string;` and a factory/class method `+(instancetype)objectWithString:(NSString *)string;`. – Both are mapped to `init!(string: String!)`, but the *init* method is called, not the class method. I could not find that explicitly in the documentation.

Comment: Well with a little bit of tweaking that was exactly what I was looking for! Better yet, thank you  to everyone for the wealth of information! It's much appreciated :)