# String With Contents Of URL?

Tags: ios, swift

So before I downloaded the recent update, the following code **worked for me:**

```
var g_home_url = String.stringWithContentsOfURL(NSURL(string: url_string), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil) // Gives me an error: "String.Type does not have a member names stringWithContentsOfUrl"
```

I am confused. What is the proper way to acieve the following objective-c method in swift?

```
NSString * g_home_url = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:home_url] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the `-initWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:` instance method instead of the `+stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:` class convenience initializer.

```
var g_home_url = String(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: url_string)!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
```

I have no idea if class convenience initializers are now unsupported in Swift, but it would make sense as they were just shorthands for the alloc-init boilerplate, which doesn't exist in Swift.

Comment: `initWithContentsOfURL` and `stringWithContentsOfURL` are mapped to the *same* Swift method, and it seems that only the init method can be called from Swift in such a case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491508/creating-an-object-in-swift-using-the-objective-c-factory-method-gives-a-compile describes a similar issue.

Comment: `contentsOfURL` will fetch the response for that url. I don't know what's the reason. I use the quote syntax to convert it now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27062454/converting-url-to-string-and-back-again/31586194#31586194

Answer (score 11):

For Swift 3 you'll have to use `String(contentsOf:encoding:)`. It throws.

```
do {
    var content = try String(contentsOf:URL(string: "http://your-URI-here")!)
}
catch let error {
    // Error handling
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At this moment (Swift 4.1.2) the only one way to send HTTP-get request from Ubuntu linux is: https://github.com/dmcyk/SwiftyCurl

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyCurl

var request = cURLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://path.to/url/")!, method: .get)
let connection = cURLConnection(useSSL: true)

do {
  let res = try connection.request(request)
  if let body: String = res.body() {
     print(body)
  }
} catch {
   prin(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here what it worked for me:
(There is no more error argument)

```
var g_home_url = try! String(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: url_string)!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

or if you want to handle the error:

```
do {
  var g_home_url = try String(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: url_string)!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
}
catch {
   print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 4 they have changed string encoding. So now it will be,

```
do {
  var g_home_url = try String(contentsOfURL: URL.init(string: url_string)!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
}
catch {
   print(error)
}
```

Comment: `do {
            let ipAddress = try String(contentsOf: url, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }`

Comment: This solution don't on Linux with Swift 4.1.1. String(contentsOf: url) returns nothing

Comment: @SergeyDi I encounter the same problem... I have also checked https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7620 , but no update yet. Do you have any workaround?

Comment: @5t111111 Only to use swift 3.x. But on 3.x version String(contentsOf also has an issue. Each time you call it, /tmp/someName.tmp file created.