# Swift How do I convert document file URLs to strings so I can display the file names in tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

Currently I have my files in an array as URLs:

```
var cafFilesArray: [NSURL] {
    return (NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(documentsDirectoryURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .SkipsHiddenFiles | .SkipsSubdirectoryDescendants | .SkipsPackageDescendants, error: nil) as! [NSURL]).sorted{$0.lastPathComponent<$1.lastPathComponent}.filter{$0.pathExtension!.lowercaseString == "caf"}
```

How do I convert an array of URLs to Strings so I can display them in a tableview.

Thanks.

Comment: `NSURL` has a `absoluteString` property

Comment: What have you tried so far? Related: [Converting URL to String and back again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27062454/converting-url-to-string-and-back-again).

Comment: also look at NSURL lastpAthComponent method which Lismore convenient for displaying file names (not the path!) in a table view

Comment: Thank you. The absoluteString works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the `NSURL` array and do `myurl.absoluteString` to convert each element to a `string` and then append it to an array.