# How to open a local pdf file in Safari or a WebView

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm using the Swift 5. This code doesn't do anything, but if it's a pdf that is on the web, it opens Safari fine.

I want to use a local pdf file that's saved locally.

```
print(file.absoluteString)
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(filePath: file.absoluteString))
```

The file path is here, and I can verify the file exists

On simulator and on iPad

```
file:///Users/admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/503B73CA-5121-40CC-AC5C-6713F47A60F7/data/Containers/Data/Application/05C1515A-26FF-4EC8-B748-03F661BF7B15/Documents/00A1.pdf

file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2797F491-6E67-492E-B6C1-03DAEDDA5783/Documents/00A1.pdf
```

I'm thinking this is a URL schema issue, that file:// is not accepted (maybe we can whitelist somehow?)

Comment: Does it open if you manually copy and paste that link into the search bar in Safari (on the simulator)?

Comment: Good point... and yes it does

Comment: What does `UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)` return? It could be that iOS doesn't handle the `file://` scheme. You could try using the `shareddocuments://` scheme instead to open the Files app. (That is, try the same URL but with `shareddocuments://` instead of `file://`.)

Comment: canOpen returns true

Comment: Does switching the schema to shareddocuments:// help?

Comment: No, it opens up the shared files app but nothing opens

Comment: why outside in Safari? Open pdf inside app in WKWebview  and give option of share for this pdf...

Comment: I did try a WebView, and it was the same issue. There is some sort of issue (based on security apparently) that it won't allow a local file to open.  After much digging, a local file must be interacted upon with the `UIDocumentInteractionController` class, and as such, I have shown a solution on how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answers I've gotten, there is no way to have Safari open a local file.

So the only method that I have gotten to work flawlessly is using the `UIDocumentInteractionController` class:

```
import UIKit

class DocumentController: NSObject, ObservableObject, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate
{
    let controller = UIDocumentInteractionController()
    func presentDocument(url: URL)
    {
        controller.delegate = self
        controller.url = url
        controller.presentPreview(animated: true)
    }

    func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController
    {
       
        return (UIApplication
            .shared
            .connectedScenes
            .compactMap { ($0 as? UIWindowScene)?.keyWindow }
            .last?.rootViewController)!
    }
}
```

Which you use by:

```
DocumentController().presentDocument(url: url)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a security feature. You can't make Safari open a local file from your application on iOS. You can open it using the PDFView, as Alexey proposed. However, since your pdf file is not a part of the application bundle, but it's in the Documents folder, you need to generate the file path this way:

```
let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("00A1.pdf")
```

Here is the complete code including the download part:

```
import UIKit
import PDFKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let remote = URL(string:"https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swift/swift_tutorial.pdf")!
        let folder = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        let local = folder.appendingPathComponent("00A1.pdf")

        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: local.path) {
            openPdf(at:local)
        } else {
            downloadFile(from:remote, to:local) { _ in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.openPdf(at:local)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func openPdf(at url: URL) {
        let pdfView = PDFView(frame: view.bounds)
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: url)
        pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        view.addSubview(pdfView)
    }
    
    func downloadFile(from remote: URL, to local:URL, completionHandler: @escaping ((Error?)->Void)) {
        let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
        let task = session.downloadTask(with: URLRequest(url:remote)) { (temp, _, error) in
            var exception = error
            if let temp = temp, exception == nil {
                do {
                    try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: temp, to: local)
                } catch {
                    exception = error
                }
            }
            completionHandler(exception)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: I still couldn't get my pdf to open even using this. I figured it out using the `UIDocumentInteractionController` class.

Comment: Great. Then it would be nice to show the solution, so that the others could make use of it, too.

Comment: I did show a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   let webView = WKWebView()
   webView.frame = view.bounds

   if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "00A1", withExtension: "pdf") {
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
   }

}
```

...and one more option using PDFView:

```
import UIKit
import PDFKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private let pdfView: PDFView = {
        let view = PDFView()
        view.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
        view.autoScales = true
        return view
    }()

    // MARK: - Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        pdfView.frame = view.bounds
    
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "00A1", ofType: "pdf") {
            if let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path)) {
                pdfView.document = pdfDocument
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: webView is not in scope... where did you declare webView?

Comment: same issue... I'm thinking this is a URL schema issue, that file:// is not accepted

Answer (score 0):

Try it with QLPreviewController, add this code where you click on file or something else.

```
import QuickLook
import UIKit

func previewDocument(with url: URL) {
        let preview = QLPreviewController()
        preview.dataSource = self
        preview.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        previewItem = url as NSURL <- your file path in URL format
        self.present(preview, animated: true)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Open with associated app:

```
NSWorkspace.shared.open(someLocalUrl)   // macOS
UIApplication.shared.open(someLocalUrl) // iOS
```

Open with some exact app:

```
// macOS
NSWorkspace.shared.open(someLocalUrl, withApplicationAt: appUrl, configuration: NSWorkspace.OpenConfiguration())

// iOS
UIApplication.shared.open( // similar to MacOS
```

PS:

URL object must be valid. Valid URLs of local files must be created with

```
URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
```

more info about URLs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59464032/4423545