# Swift 'String.Type' does not have a member named 'stringWithContentsOfURL'

Tags: ios, string, swift, nserror

Hi I am beginning with swift and I got the error:

> 'String.Type' does not have a member named 'stringWithContentsOfURL'

Here is my code:

```
 func searchFlickrForString(searchStr:String, completion:(searchString:String!, flickrPhotos:NSMutableArray!, error:NSError!)->()){

    let searchURL:String = FlickrHelper.URLForSearchString(searchStr)
    let queue:dispatch_queue_t  = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)

    dispatch_async(queue, {
        var error:NSError?
        let searchResultString:String! = String.stringWithContentsOfURL(NSURL.URLWithString(searchURL), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)
```

Can anyone please suggest a suitable fix towards this problem as I can't seem to find any applicable resources online?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26532113/string-with-contents-of-url-swift

Comment: Unfortunately the post didn't resolve the error

Comment: What is the new error or are you saying you are getting the same error?

Comment: I getting the same error even after using the answer provided in the question link above

Comment: and you are sure you changed it to something like this: let searchResultString = String(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: searchURL)!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)